# difference between "specific " and "particular"

Tags: word-usage

I have been confusing "specific" and "particular" for a long time. After some effort I was stuck.

I was learning a [Cambridge Dictionary post](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/a-an-and-the) when I found an example of the use of "specific"

> We only use "the" with general plural nouns when we are referring to a **specific** set within a general class of people or things.
>
> The books were all over the floor. I mean **specific** books (that you and I know).

Imagine that, there are some books that Chollet and Schmidhuber (I made up the names) both know, and some of them are being on the floor.

Generally, "books" may refer to all the books in the world. Some of them is a **specific** set, the ones that Chollet and Schmidhuber know, what about "particular" in this context?

Are the books on the floor the **particular** ones? Is the one Chollet is picking up the **particular** one?

In the story of Chollet and Schmidhuber's books, in what situation "particular" and "specific" are interchangeable?

---

TL;DR

Just to show my effort.

Cambridge Dictionary gives this definition of "specific"

> relating to one thing and not others; **particular**

where "particular" is used to define "specific", and this definition of "particular"

> special, or this and not any other

I've gone through a few posts, e.g. [quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-specific-and-particular), [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252054/difference-between-certain-specific-and-particular), [hinative](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/390778) and some others. The explanation and examples in most of which are also hardly distinguishable, some says they are interchangeable without saying in what situations. The one in hinative is easily understand to me

> "I only like a **specific** brand of ice cream."
>
> "I enjoy this **particular** brand of ice cream because I love chocolate."

I guess I got a clearer understanding of them, though the one for "specific" does not sound like a real life situation. Who would talk about their favorite ice cream that way ~ Why not give the name of that brand directly.

---

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252054/difference-between-certain-specific-and-particular  this question might be helpful.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Thx. That link is exactly the same one I attached in the OP, which says "specific and particular are completely interchangeable in every case I can think of".